# How do nested CSS overflow-(x) properties interact?

Tags: css

I think that this is enough to pose my question.

The following is observed inside an ExtJS 4.1.1 panel in a border layout with a slider for resizing of a panel containing a tree panel. The text in the middle shows up with an elipsis truncation, and the tree panel exhibits a tiny amount of horizontal scrollbar sufficient to make the ... appear and disappear. What's going on? Is the 'hidden' triggering the ...?

```
<div style='overflow-x: auto'>
<table>
 <tbody>
   <tr> <!-- no spec , chrome says 'visible'-->
    <td style='overflow-x: hidden'>
     <div style='overflow-x: hidden'>
       <span style='overflow-x: visible">
         This is a fairly long string
       </span>
     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Don't think the span is going to reflect overflow unless you change it to `display:block` or `display:inline-block`. Also, I tried setting up an example but I think we need to know where the dimensions are being set to give a good answer.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JEgPH/ - I doubt this is what you are describing, so please modify to reflect the problem.

Comment: OK, display: is the problem. Thanks.